# Как отправить через телеграм бот пользователю кастомный эмодзи

Tags: javascript, python, c#, telegram-bot

Как отправить пользователю кастомный эмодзи(которые пользователи делают через бота) в тексте сообщения. Например бот должен отправить сообщение "Привет✋" но этот эмодзи "✋" должен быть из набора кастомных эмодзи, то есть, видоизмененный, если в пользовательском наборе есть его видоизмененный версия, в противном случае отправляется обычный.

Comment: Для тех, кто не пользуется телеграмм (меня), "кастомный эмодзи" - это ваш функционал, или самого телеграмма? Если ваш, то наверно, у вас это должно быть все в базе, из которой вы достаете нужную информацию и по ней отправляете нужное, не? Если это функционал телеграмма, то мне кажется, это часть UI, а в этом случае, сам ТГ должен подставлять все каждому клиенту индивидуально.

Comment: В данный момент это невозможно, только не премиумные стикеры/эмодзи

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что вы подразумеваете под кастомным эмодзи в Телеграм.
Если речь о пользователях, которые будут писать сообщения, то они могут просто скопировать любой понравившийся им эмодзи из интернета и вставить в сообщение, главное, чтобы он поддерживался самим Телеграмом, а если вы хотите обратиться к доступному набору эмодзи посредством бота, тогда вам стоит научиться пользоваться библиотекой emoji, пример как пользоваться прилагаю:

```
import emoji
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"], state="*")
async def user_emoji(message: Message):
    await message.answer(text="Выберите вашу роль." + emoji.emojize(":brain:"), reply_markup=choise_role)
    await RegistrationStates.choice_of_role.set()
```

Comment: Вы не поняли о чём речь https://journal.tinkoff.ru/telegram-premium-emoji/